# Exporting a virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, export

I'm trying to export a VM running Windows server 2016 (in Hyper-V, on W10 pc).

I have to export/import to a share-folder that is on the machine I want to export to, but when I click "Browse" in export-mode I can not find my shares. They do show up if I use regular file explorer.
Copy & paste the path does not work for some reason. 
I am admin so I can access anything.

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Try using powershell. Either it’ll work and that’s great or it’ll give you an error message to work with, and that’s a start on unpacking what the fault is and either way you’re winning. Try something like:

```
Export-VM -Name <vm name> -Path \<path>
```

E.g.

```
Export-VM -name testserver -path \\server\share\folder
```